# how to call pipe based upon events in angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, pipe, angular2-ngmodel

I have created a custom pipe that converts inches to feet inches format (65 = 5' 5") and it working fine when rendering the data on page i the text box.
The same text box I want to modify and update it, but whenever I try modify the value for each entry it applying pipe and converting to required format and that is causing problem.I want to apply pipe only after the text box entry completes while modifying.
is there any way I can  apply pipe only when '(ionBlur)' instead '(ionChange)'

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of TankData" >
          <ion-col>
            <ion-input type="text" [ngModel]="item.value | feetInch"  (ngModelChange)="item.value=$event"  (ionBlur)="notify($event)"></ion-input>
          </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
```

Comment: You'd probably have to store two values and onBlur, assign the item.value to the second value. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ion-input type="text" [ngModel]="item.value | feetInch" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn:'blur'}"  (ngModelChange)="item.value=$event" ></ion-input>
```

ngModelOptions option worked for me